# Javascript For Loop with setInterval makes jQuery animation too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have a setInterval function that calls a for loop, looping through each HTML text item on my page. If there is a text update (checked with AJAX), the html text flashes with flashfunction().

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval("html_update(html_text)", 11000);   // influences flash time
});
```

This works fine for checking updates. But if there is an update, the animation triggers too fast (about 4x as fast as it does OUTSIDE the for loop)!

Here is the code to check an array of html text boxes to see if there is an update. If there is an update, the box will flash:

```
for (var i=0; i < id_array_len; i++) {
....some AJAX calls here...

if (httpRequest.ResponseText == 'update') {
$("#htmltext").css("background", color);
$("#htmltext").animate( { "opacity" : 0.4 }, 700, function() {
        $("#htmltext"+id).css("background", color);
        $("#meme"+id).animate( { "opacity" : 1 }, 300)
    });
}
```

Outside the for loop, the animation jQuery works at the correct speed. Inside the for loop, it flashes 4x as quickly...

Please help and thank you!!

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. What animation are you referring to as being "too fast?" Do you not want all updated items to flash at the same time? What were you trying to accomplish with the second `setTimeout`?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I mean that the animation runs 4x as quickly inside the for loop. It runs at the correct speed outside the for loop.  I was just experimenting with the setTimeout -- didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little confused by what 'too fast'  means, but I suspect that you want to introduce a delay before triggering the animation. You can do that with jQuery's [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method.

```
$('selector').delay(3000).animate({...});
```

Comment: By fast, I mean -- outside the for loop, the animation works at the correct speed. But inside the for loop, it flashes within a few seconds!

I tried the .delay method and now the color is simply frozen at 0.4 opacity?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to post more code and more context about what you want. It is too ambiguous right now to answer.

Comment: Yea, please provide more information on your problem. Its pretty unclear as of now. But I GUESS the problem of animation being 'fast' is due to the absence of clearInterval method.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the original question with a clearer explanation of what's happening. I'm using the setInterval method to continuously check for updates to the html boxes. If there is an update, I want the box to flash -- but at the correct speed.

Comment: I think the issue is you're recursively calling the setInterval, so each time it's called it layers upon itself. If it first animates every 200 milliseconds and its called again it has two instances that each animate every 200 miliseconds giving the appearance that it is animating every 100 milliseconds. To fix this you should call setInterval after the loop has ended.